# Suggested Articles Sidebar Not Visible After Return From Custom VF Edit Page

Tags: visualforce

We have built an visualforce page that replaces the standard case create and update screens. It works well and seem to do everything it needs to. The only issue comes from when the case it viewed from inside the service console view. After creation of a new case, or editing of one when you are returned to the case view, that bar that is supposed to show up on the right hand side called 'suggested articles' is not visible.

On my visualforce page I have over-riden the standard save functionality, so I am returning a page reference to the case ID. My guess is that there is some parameter I need to pass in the URL. My first thought was it might have soemething to do with the isdtp param (http://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/11/magic-isdtp-param.html) that can be used to show headers and footers, and sure enough the standard console links to include the param and have it set it 'vw'. Attempting to manually include that param in the return page reference didn't make any difference.

I also notice links loaded in the console are not actually standard href links, but instead a javascript link where the object id, and the isdtp param are fed into a javascript function called srcUp. Attempting to call this function manually doesn't seem to do anything, which is kind of weird.

Inspecting the return URL from a standard edit page in the console via firebug didn't show me anything great either.

so that's basically it. I'd love for my custom visualforce edite/create page to work like a standard one and show the suggested articles sidebar once the user is returned to the case, but it seems I am not constructing the page reference properly, or am missing some param.

Comment: could you find an solution to address this problem? What specific params are needed to retain the Standard Page layout with Highlight / Side panel?